# Reading wrong data on OpenCL

Tags: c++, c, arrays, memory, opencl

I faced with the problem that the kernel writes data in wrong place or host reads data incorrectly sometimes. I write the same data (index at which I write the data) to two global arrays with different types. To ensure that the index is corrent are used the global counter which incremented by means of atom_inc. The problem occures when data are read from second array on the host. 
For instance:

```
.....
output array index: 442: (output1 value:442.0000     output2 value:442) 
output array index: 443: (output1 value:443.0000     output2 value:443) 
output array index: 444: (output1 value:444.0000     output2 value:444) 
output array index: 445: (output1 value:445.0000     output2 value:445) 
output array index: 446: (output1 value:446.0000     output2 value:1152892928) 
output array index: 447: (output1 value:447.0000     output2 value:447) 
output array index: 448: (output1 value:448.0000     output2 value:1152909312) 
output array index: 449: (output1 value:449.0000     output2 value:1152917504) 
output array index: 450: (output1 value:450.0000     output2 value:1152925696)
......
```

As you can see at indicies 446, 448, 449 and 450+ output2 contains wrong values. What can be the possible reason of this?

Device: ATI Radeon HD5750

Code sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <OpenCL/OpenCL.h>

// wtf example
const char *programSource =
"__kernel void kernel1(__global uint *counter,\n" \
"__global float *weights,\n" \
"__global uint *weights_pos)\n" \
"{\n"\
"const uint global_size = get_global_size(0);\n" \
"const uint global_id = get_global_id(0);\n" \
"uint local_id = get_local_id(0);\n" \

"if(global_id == 0) {\n" \
"counter[5] = 0; // set index of pos in weights to zero\n" \
"}\n" \

"uint insert_index = atom_inc(&counter[5]);\n" \
"weights[insert_index] = insert_index;\n" \
"weights_pos[insert_index] = insert_index;\n" \
"}";

void art_process_sinogram(const char* tiff_filename,
                          const float *angles2,
                          const unsigned int n_angles2,
                          const unsigned int n_ray2s,
                          const float distanc2e)
{
  /******************************
   * OPENCL ENVIRONMENT
   */
  cl_int status;
  cl_uint numPlatforms = 0;
  cl_platform_id *platforms = NULL;
  cl_device_id device_id;

  //discover platforms
  status = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &numPlatforms);
  platforms = (cl_platform_id*)malloc(numPlatforms * sizeof(cl_platform_id));
  status = clGetPlatformIDs(numPlatforms, platforms, NULL);

  //discover devices
  cl_uint numDevices = 0;
  cl_device_id *devices = NULL;

  status = clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 0, NULL, &numDevices);
  devices = (cl_device_id*)malloc(numDevices * sizeof(cl_device_id));
  status = clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, numDevices, devices, NULL);
  device_id = devices[1];
  //create context
  cl_context context = NULL;
  context = clCreateContext(NULL, numDevices, devices, NULL, NULL, &status);

  cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **)&programSource, NULL, &status);
  clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
  cl_kernel  kernel_weights = clCreateKernel(program, "kernel1", &status);

  //create queue
  cl_command_queue command_queue1 = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &status);

  /******************************
   * HARDWARE PARAMETERS
   */
  cl_uint wavefronts_per_SIMD = 7;
  size_t global_work_size;
  size_t local_work_size = 64;

  cl_uint max_compute_units;

  clGetDeviceInfo(device_id, CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS, sizeof(cl_uint), &max_compute_units, NULL);

  size_t wg_count = max_compute_units * wavefronts_per_SIMD;
  global_work_size = wg_count * local_work_size;

  /**************************** DATA PART *************************************/

  size_t w_portion_size = 768 * sizeof(cl_float);
  size_t w_pos_portion_size = 768 * sizeof(cl_uint);

  size_t counters_data_size = 6 * sizeof(cl_uint);
  cl_uint counters_data[6];
  counters_data[0] = 1;
  counters_data[1] = 2; // max number of the cells intersected by the ray
  counters_data[2] = 3;
  counters_data[3] = 4;
  counters_data[4] = 5; // same to the number of rays
  counters_data[5] = 0; // counter inside kernel

  /*****************
   * Main buffers
   */
  cl_mem weights1_buffer = clCreateBuffer(context,
                                          CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,
                                          w_portion_size,
                                          NULL,
                                          NULL);

  cl_mem weights_pos1_buffer = clCreateBuffer(context,
                                              CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,
                                              w_pos_portion_size,
                                              NULL,
                                              NULL);
  /*****************
   * Supplement buffers (constant)
   */
  cl_mem counters_data_buffer = clCreateBuffer(context,
                                               CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
                                               counters_data_size,
                                               NULL,
                                               &status);


  cl_event supplement_buffer_ready[1];

  status = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue1,
                                counters_data_buffer,
                                CL_FALSE,
                                0,
                                counters_data_size,
                                counters_data,
                                0,
                                NULL,
                                &supplement_buffer_ready[0]);

  status = clSetKernelArg(kernel_weights, 0, sizeof(void *), (void *)&counters_data_buffer);
  status = clSetKernelArg(kernel_weights, 1, sizeof(void *), (void *)&weights1_buffer);
  status = clSetKernelArg(kernel_weights, 2, sizeof(void *), (void *)&weights_pos1_buffer);

  status = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue1,
                                  kernel_weights,
                                  1, // work dimensional 1D, 2D, 3D
                                  NULL, // offset
                                  &global_work_size, // total number of WI
                                  &local_work_size, // nomber of WI in WG
                                  1, // num events in wait list
                                  supplement_buffer_ready,  // event wait list
                                  NULL); // event

  clFinish(command_queue1);
  cl_float *output1 = (cl_float *) clEnqueueMapBuffer(command_queue1,
                                                      weights1_buffer,//*pmain_weights_buffer,
                                                      CL_TRUE,
                                                      CL_MAP_READ,
                                                      0,
                                                      w_portion_size,
                                                      0, NULL, NULL, NULL);
  cl_uint *output2 = malloc(w_portion_size);
  status = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue1, weights_pos1_buffer,
                               CL_TRUE, 0, w_pos_portion_size, output2,
                               0, NULL, NULL);

  clFinish(command_queue1);
  for(int i = 0; i < 790; ++i) {
    printf("output array index: %d: (output1 value:%.4f \t output2 value:%d) \n", i, output1[i], output2[i]);
  }
}
```

**SOLUTION:**

The kernel should be looks like (need checking index):

```
  __kernel void k_1(__global uint *counter, 
                    __global uint *weights, 
                    __global uint2 *weights_pos)
 {
    const uint global_size = get_global_size(0);
    const uint global_id = get_global_id(0);
    uint local_id = get_local_id(0);

    uint insert_index = atom_inc(&counter[5]);
    if(insert_index < 768) {
       weights[insert_index]= insert_index;
       weights_pos[insert_index].x = insert_index;
       weights_pos[insert_index].y = insert_index;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post some actual code and not just a link whose destination you will remove anyway once you got your question answered.

Comment: @Christian Rau, Yes, you right

Comment: I tested your code on intel implementation, and I get every single value corrupted. Your code seems fine to me tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kernel should be looks like (need checking index):

```
__kernel void k_1(__global uint *counter, 
                __global uint *weights, 
                __global uint2 *weights_pos)
{
   const uint global_size = get_global_size(0);
   const uint global_id = get_global_id(0);
   uint local_id = get_local_id(0);

   uint insert_index = atom_inc(&counter[5]);

   if(insert_index < 768) {
     weights[insert_index]= insert_index;
     weights_pos[insert_index].x = insert_index;
    weights_pos[insert_index].y = insert_index;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are messing up with buffer dimensions.

1) Your buffers contains 768 elements each (see initialization of `w_portion_size` and `w_pos_portion_size`)

2) Workgroup size on my machine is 896 (see initialization of `wg_count`)

3) You print out 790 values.

Apart from this, one conceptual error is here:

```
if(global_id == 0) {
     counter[5] = 0; // set index of pos in weights to zero
}
//atomic increments on counter[5]
```

You can't assume that the first virtual processor will execute this line before the others. You should completely remove this line, since you initialize `counter[5]` on the host side. (I believe that this is the cause of your problem, but I can't reproduce that).

After fixing these problems your code seems to run fine (intel implementation).

Comment: Thanks you for efforts. I agree with your statements but anyway fixing it didn't bring any positive results.